# как из дочернего компонента изменить список в родительском?

Tags: vue.js

у меня еще есть мысль что нужно создавать метод в родителе, но в таком случае я не знаю как из дочернего компонента вызвать метод который в родителе

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['item','key2'],
  template: `
    <li>
      {{ item }}
      <button @click="removeItem(key2)">remove</button>
    </li>
  `,
  methods:{
    removeItem: function(id){
      console.log(id)
      //что нужно дописать тут, что б из родительского компонента удалить объект по которому кликаю
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  components:['child'],
  data:{
    list:{
      "1":'item 1',
      "2":'item 2',
      "3":'item 3',
      "4":'item 4',
      "5":'item 5',
      "6":'item 6',
      "7":'item 7' 
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<ul id="app">
  <child v-for="(item, id) in list" :item="item" :key2="id">s</child>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обратиться к *"родительскому"* объекту `data` можно с помощью `this.$root.$data`. Удалить же элемент, можно с помощью [Vue.delete()](http://ruvuejsorg.surge.sh/v2/api/#Vue-delete)

Стало быть в вашем случаи, ответом на вопрос, который написан комментарием в методе `removeItem`, будет выглядеть примерно так:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['item', 'key2'],
  template: `
    <li>
      {{ item }}
      <button @click="removeItem(key2)">remove</button>
    </li>
  `,
  methods: {
    removeItem: function(id) {
      console.log(this.$root.$data.list[id]);
      Vue.delete(this.$root.$data.list, id)
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: ['child'],
  data: {
    list: {
      "1": 'item 1',
      "2": 'item 2',
      "3": 'item 3',
      "4": 'item 4',
      "5": 'item 5',
      "6": 'item 6',
      "7": 'item 7'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<ul id="app">
  <child v-for="(item, id) in list" :item="item" :key2="id">s</child>
</ul>
```

Однако, если всё-же делать более корректно *(как справедливо заметил товарищ @yarkov_aleksei)*, то необходимо, создать метод в родителе и с помощью *[$emit](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit)* уже обращаться к нему, таким образом:

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['item', 'key2'],
  template: `
    <li>
      {{ item }}
      <button @click="removeItem(key2)">remove</button>
    </li>
  `,
  methods: {
    removeItem (id) {
      this.$emit('remove', id)
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: ['child'],
  methods: {
    removeItem (id) {
      console.log(id)
      Vue.delete(this.list, id)
    }
  },
  data: {
    list: {
      "1": 'item 1',
      "2": 'item 2',
      "3": 'item 3',
      "4": 'item 4',
      "5": 'item 5',
      "6": 'item 6',
      "7": 'item 7'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<ul id="app">
        <child v-for="(item, id) in list"
      :item="item"
          :key2="id"
          @remove="removeItem">remove</child>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Но лучше так не делать никогда, а эмитить событие в родителя (наверх) и слушать его там

Comment: Вот вам пример: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KsPQbzrea0j4Zf2DdLy